# failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: User.authorities, could not initialize proxy - no Session

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

In my Spring Boot/Data/JPA application I have a following entity:

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "graph.User", attributeNodes = { @NamedAttributeNode("authorities") })
@Table(name = "users")
public class User extends BaseEntity implements UserDetails {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8884184875433252086L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "users_id_seq", sequenceName = "users_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "users_id_seq")
    private Long id;

    ...

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "users_authorities", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "authority_id") })
    private Set<Authority> authorities = new HashSet<Authority>();

}
```

This is my Spring `AuthenticationService` :

```
@Service
public class AuthenticationService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userService.findByUsername(username);

        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("User %s does not exist!", username));
        }

        return user;
    }

}
```

During the application startup I'm receiving following exception:

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.example.common.model.user.User.authorities, could not initialize proxy - no Session
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:576)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:555)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.iterator(PersistentSet.java:180)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationToken.<init>(AbstractAuthenticationToken.java:61)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.<init>(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.java:72)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.createSuccessAuthentication(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:224)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:196)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:167)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:217)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

How to configure my application in order to correctly handle `User.authorities` with `FetchType.LAZY` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give it a try;

In Service;

```
User user = userService.findByUsername(username);
user.getAuthorities().size(); //You may need call this line in userService.findByUsername(username); method
```

In User;

```
public Set<Authority> getAuthorities(){
    return authorities;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the same result - failed to lazily initialize a collection of role

Comment: @alexanoid Did you try it in UserService instead AuthenticationService? and do you have transaction?

Comment: Sorry, my bad! In UserService it is working fine! Is it a good place to go with ?

Comment: Yes, We have to make hibernate get collections in session context.

Comment: this solution works also for me, but is there any more elegant way to achieve that?

Comment: @fascynacja I think this is the best way. (better than using eager which is the other solution)

Answer (score 2):

just initialize authority manually as below:

```
User user = userService.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Username not found"));

Set<Authority> authorities = user.getAuthorities();

Hibernate.initialize(authorities);

return user;
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution that worked for me was adding in Domain class, setting the following  annotation:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```

Comment: While it's a working solution, eager fetching is not always desired behavior

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this same problem today. What worked for me:

1. Annotate the service method (`loadUserByUsername`) with `@Transactional`
2. Then add to the service method:

```java
Hibernate.initialize(user.getAuthorities());
```